# How does "per-coordinate normalization" affect covariance matrix norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, covariance, positive-definite

Suppose we normalize our data so that per-coordinate variances are one, can we bound the effect this has on the spectral radius of the covariance matrix?

More precisely, suppose our data-points are stacked as rows in $n\times d$ data matrix $X$ with $X^TX$ having full-rank, trace $d$ and spectral radius $\sigma$. Compute normalized spectral radius $\sigma_n$ as follows

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
L&=&\text{Diag}(X^TX)\\
\sigma_n&=&\lambda_\max(L^{-1/2}X^TXL^{-1/2})
\end{array}
$$

Can we put bounds on $\sigma/\sigma_n$?

In numerical [simulations](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/normalized-effective-rank.nb), normalized spectral radius stays close to original spectral radius. For instance, take some random $500 \times 500$ covariance matrices with eigenvalue decay $O(1/k)$. Applying normalization operation decreases spectral radius by 15-25%

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to bound without extra assumptions. In general, diagonal preconditioning won't necessarily improve the conditioning. See $H = \begin{bmatrix}0.17 & -0.49 & -0.19 & -0.36 \\
-0.49 & 2.34 & 0.71 & 1.79 \\
-0.19 & 0.71 & 0.32 & 0.53 \\
-0.36 & 1.79 & 0.53 & 1.44
\end{bmatrix}$